Usage of “Effects”
I came across this sentence:

“This new patch commit can be cherry-picked directly to the main branch to fix the bug before it effects more users.”

I find the usage of “effects” here to be weird. Is this a valid and natural usage? I feel like “affects” is what should have been written. I also find it more natural but that just might be personal preference.
I tried to Google about the difference between them and about using “effects” as a verb but all I could find was using “effect” (without the “s”) as a verb.
Thanks!

It’s a spelling error involving two words that, in many dialects, are homophones. The verb effect means to cause or bring about.
